# Is there any plugin for push notification in phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I want to send notifications to android devices using phonegap. 
Anyone can guide me how to demonstrate it?

Comment: Please try to only post questions related to programming issues. Issues that don't require code examples and help debugging are off-topic here. As the answer below notes, try google or forums for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

Like this one? https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

For the future though, please note that I found this as a first result of the following Google research:

https://www.google.com/search?q=android+push+notification+plugin&ie=UTF-8&sa=Search